Extracting custom field value from WooCommerce checkout form
I am currently using WooCommerce checkout field plugin and been trying to extract a custom value field I created so I can send it through an API to a different platform but no success.
Here are the custom fields:
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
    $billing_company = $order->get_billing_company();
    $firstName = $order->get_billing_first_name();
    $lastName = $order->get_billing_last_name();
    $email = $order->get_billing_email();

    $role = 'Company Admin';

    $industry = 'Guide';
    $businessType = 'Private';
    $employeeCount = $employeeCount = get_post_meta( $this->order->get_id(), 'employee_count', true );
    $industryClassification = '92 - Public Administration';
    $locationName = 'Primary Location';
    $zip = $zip = (int)$order->get_billing_postcode();

The fields from $role to $locationName are the custom ones but the one that I am focusing on is $employeeCount. Once I get that extracted, will be able to do the other ones.
I followed this SO question and looked for the meta_key, which is employee_count but still not getting the value extracted from the custom field.
I also followed the documentation but nothing clear there.
Would appreciate any help or insight regards this.

Try $employeeCount = $order->get_meta('employee_count');

@LoicTheAztec Quick question, if I were to use the dropdown option field in checkout field, would the same $order->get_meta() works?

Yes, it does work with any custom field (metadata): $order->get_meta('the_meta_key');
